# How do I opt-out of "Expert Alert" emails from Experts Exchange?

Tags: experts-exchange

I get these alerts too often. Ideally I wouldn't receive them at all.

I have opted out of receiving the two categories of emails shown on the settings page, Newsletters and Marketing Email, but I can't find the area for Expert Alerts.

With out resorting to an email filter, does anyone know how to get rid of these emails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question alerts are set in your Saved Search options.  Login, then go here:

http://www.experts-exchange.com/savedSearches.jsp

and either edit the saved search to remove email notifications or delete the search entirely.  That will stop the emails immediately.  It's not affected by Newsletters or Marketing because this is something you set.